# AngularJS json multidimensional array doesn't not look like it should be

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, multidimensional-array

This is an AngularJS problem; I have a simple form:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="qus" placeholder="Enter Question" ng-model="qus">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="op1" placeholder="Option 1" ng-model="op1">
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="correct1">Correct</label>
<button class="form-control btn btn-primary" ng-click = "save()">Save</button>
<pre  ng-bind="dataShow"></pre>
```

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('qApp', []);
app.controller('qCtrl', function($scope) {
    var set = [];
    var op1 = [];
    $scope.save = function (){
        if($scope.correct1!==true){$scope.correct1=false;}      
        op1.push($scope.op1, $scope.correct1);
        var qus = [$scope.qus, op1];
        set.push(qus);
        $scope.dataShow = JSON.stringify(set); 
    };

});
```

Outputs:

After using `JSON.stringify` for the first entry the output looks like this:

```
[
 ["q1",["o1",false]]
]
```

and the output for the second entry is:

```
[
 ["q1", ["o1",false,"o2",true]], 
 ["q2", ["o1",false,"o2",true]]
]
```

But I wanted something like this:

```
[
 ["q1", ["o1",false,]], 
 ["q2", ["o2",true]]
]
```

How to do that? `true`/`false` is the value of a check box.

Comment: can you provide plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: initialize op1 inside save method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Nagesh Sanika is correct. Each question will have a list of options. So you can create the options array every-time when a new question is added to the set.

```
var app = angular.module('qApp', []);
app.controller('qCtrl', function($scope) {
    var set = [];

    $scope.save = function (){
        var op1 = [];  // Moved it inside the save method
        if($scope.correct1!==true){$scope.correct1=false;}      
        op1.push($scope.op1, $scope.correct1);
        var qus = [$scope.qus, op1];
        set.push(qus);
        $scope.dataShow = JSON.stringify(set); 
    };

});
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tiCMGqPZlO0b2Ou5u34n?p=preview).

Comment: you can do directly `var op1 = [$scope.op1, $scope.correct1];` :-)

Comment: @Grundy, That's correct for the given scenario. But if multiple options are to be entered, we need to add then using `push `method.

Answer (score 1):

To get your result, you need to empty the op1 array each time.

```
var app = angular.module('qApp', []);
app.controller('qCtrl', function($scope) {
var set = [];
var op1 = [];
$scope.save = function (){
    if($scope.correct1!==true){
      $scope.correct1=false;
    }      

    op1.push($scope.op1, $scope.correct1);

    var qus = [$scope.qus, op1];

    set.push(qus);
    op1=[];
    $scope.dataShow = JSON.stringify(set); 
 };
});
```

Hope this works :)